# Model not update in angular-xeditable, angular Ui-Select

Tags: angularjs, x-editable, angular-ui-select

i used [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) in [angular-xeditable](https://github.com/vitalets/angular-xeditable).
in [this sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/YTuBlsxEjCpXeILvpjry?p=preview) all is ok but,  Model not updated (foo.bar not change when select an item). can you help me?

```
<span editable-ui-select="foo.bar" e-ng-model="foo.bar" e-name="bar" name="bar" e-form="editableForm">
      {{foo.bar.name}}
      <editable-ui-select-match placeholder="Search..." style="width:500px">
        {{$select.selected.name}}
      </editable-ui-select-match>
      <editable-ui-select-choices repeat="b in bars | filter:$select.search">
        {{b.name}}
      </editable-ui-select-choices>
    </span>
```

Comment: Are you sure that x-editable has implemented ui-select?  I don't see it anywhere in the x-editable documentation

Comment: thanx for your response, x-editable not implemented ui-select, but the sample has a directive for use ui-select in x-editable, all is ok, but only model not update when user selected an item. plase see the example.

Comment: Have you found out the solution for this ? Thanks.

Comment: no solution found :((

Comment: Hence are you using any alternative api for that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still testing, but After Many a cry and some prayers. The following modification works for me. got the idea from https://habrahabr.ru/post/277001/

**ui-select support:**
https://github.com/vitalets/angular-xeditable/pull/300/files#diff-90635473805044e26bceb2f7ffecfa82

I've added 2 lines to the render function above code

```
this.inputEl.attr('on-select', 'fooEvent($item)');
this.inputEl.attr('ng-model', '$parent.$data');
```

`var dir = editableDirectiveFactory({ 
            directiveName: 'editableUiSelect',
            inputTpl: '<ui-select></ui-select>',
            render: function () {
                this.parent.render.call(this);
                this.inputEl.append(rename('ui-select-match', match));
                this.inputEl.append(rename('ui-select-choices', choices));
                this.inputEl.attr('on-select', 'fooEvent($item)');
                this.inputEl.attr('ng-model', '$parent.$data');
            } 
        });`